# Update pointer on page content change

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

When I'm hovering over an element that has a `cursor: pointer;` style (whether default or not) and I click this element to trigger a content change, the mouse pointer doesn't reflect the change of an underlying content and stays the same.

The behavior is correct in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE and Opera the mouse pointer doesn't update its style until it is moved. Is there a proper way to fix this? I thought about moving the pointer by a pixel or so, but that will certainly trigger some other bugs and I would expect such thing to be blocked by any decent content blocker.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the window's cursor to 'wait' while you're making the change, then take it off when you're finished.  This might trigger the buggy browsers to recheck what the cursor should actually be, and would have the side effect that if the change takes longer than expected the user will see feedback that something is happening.

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but it didn't work. There is no request done so it is really quick (the wait cursor doesn't even show) and I don't want to add artificial delay there.